# Library data.table makes problems on Mac (R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing")

Tags: r, data.table

Data on: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/oq9v7nbg7baadm8/QmDuVpTk2v

The code:

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(lubridate)

df = fread("Watertable_fluctuations_All_Original.txt", 
           skip = 1, header = T) # dropbox file
df = df[, date := dmy(date)]
tables(df)
dfm = melt(df, id.vars = "date", value.name = "water.level")

wl.threshold = -0.22


dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, keyby = variable] # count per measuring station
setkey(dfm,variable); dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, by = key(dfm)].
```

plot:

```
library(openair)
timePlot(dfm[variable == "Yel342(2010)"],
         pollutant = "water.level", 
         smooth = T, 
         ref.y = wl.threshold)
```

produces following problems:

```
> tables(df)
```

Fehler in if (mb) { : 
  Argument kann nicht als logischer Wert interpretiert werden
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In if (mb) { :
  Bedingung hat Länge > 1 und nur das erste Element wird benutzt
AND

```
> dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, keyby = variable] # count per measuring station
```

Fehler in `[.data.frame`(dfm, water.level < wl.threshold, .N, keyby = variable) : 
  unbenutztes Argument (keyby = variable)
AND

```
> setkey(dfm,variable); dfm[water.level < wl.threshold,.N, by = key(dfm)].
```

Fehler in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose) : x is not a data.table
AND

```
+ ref.y = wl.threshold)
```

Fehler in `[.data.frame`(dfm, variable == "Yel342(2010)") : 
  Objekt 'variable' nicht gefunden
HELP!